# How to resolve Unable to find valid certification path to requested target for AWS Java Application?

Tags: amazon-web-services

My network is behind ZScaler Proxy. I have installed AWS CLI. I have added all the Amazon Root CA Certificates along with ZScaler CA Root Certificate in a pem file. I have setup `AWS_CA_Bundle` and my aws cli command for fetching secretsmanager worked.

But when on the same machine, I am trying to fetch SecretManagers using AWS SDK, it gives exception - `Unable to find valid certification path to requested target`.

Can someone guide me what needs to be done?

Below is the source code

```
public class AwsSecretManager {
public static AWSSecretManagerPojo getRedshiftCredentialsFromSecretManager(String secretName) throws JsonUtilityException, AwsSecretException {
    String secret = getSecret(secretName);
    // Gaurav added this.
    System.out.println("secret \n" + secret);
    if (!StringUtility.isNullOrEmpty(secret)) {
        AWSSecretManagerPojo AWSSecretManagerPojo = GsonUtility.getInstance().fromJson(secret, AWSSecretManagerPojo.class,
                EdelweissConstant.GSON_TAG);


        return AWSSecretManagerPojo;
    } else {
        throw new AwsSecretException("unable to get redshift credentials from aws secret manager");
    }
}

private static String getSecret(String secretName) {
    // Gaurav commented below and manually supplied the secret as SSL issue is there.

    String region = EdelweissConstant.AWS_SECRET_MANAGER_REGION;
    AWSSecretsManager client = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(region)
            .build();
    String secret = null;
    GetSecretValueRequest getSecretValueRequest = new GetSecretValueRequest()
            .withSecretId(secretName);
    GetSecretValueResult getSecretValueResult = client.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest);
    if (getSecretValueResult.getSecretString() != null) {
        secret = getSecretValueResult.getSecretString();
    }


    return secret;
}
```

}[image]

Comment: Could you post your relevant code to the question? It would help to understand the context.

Comment: Source code and error log added to the question. Please check

Comment: any updates on this? facing same issue!

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old but other answers to this topic were all programmatic and on a per-application basis which I didn't like, since I wanted this to work for all my applications. To anyone stumbling upon this, these are the steps that I took to fix this issue in my application.

1. Download the AWS Root CAs from [here](https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/). CA1 was good enough for me, but you may need others as well. Java requires the `.der` format one. You can also get the `.pem` file, but you'll need to convert it to `.der`. Note that the certificate from Amazon had a `.cer` extension, but it's still compatible.
2. Verify that the certificate is legible for the Java `keytool`:

```
$ keytool -v -printcert -file AmazonRootCA1.cer
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: <...>
         SHA256: <...>
```

3. Optionally, verify the public key hash if you'd like (outside the scope of this answer, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46309453) if you want).
4. Import the certificate file to your Java keystore. You can do this for your entire JRE by using the `keytool` command as follows and answering `yes` when prompted:

```
keytool -importcert -alias <some_name> -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -file AmazonRootCA1.cer
```

If you've changed the default Java keystore pass (`changeit`), you'll obviously need to use that one instead.

After this your application should be able to connect to AWS without any certificate issues.

Answer (score -1):

I removed all the Amazon Certificates and just added ZScaler Root Certiicate. And it resolved the issue.

Comment: Where exactly did you add the Root Certificat and where did you get it from? I'm having a similar issue with Salesforce CLI and ZScaler and with more info I might be able to replicate your solution.

Comment: Please elaborate on the solution